# Join multiple tables in Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have over 100 tables in my BQ, but i would like to create a single table with all the tables.

How is this possible? Now i am using the below query to export data manually by table.

```
SELECT 
date as Date,
SUM(totals.visits) as TotalVisits
From
[1243.ga_sessions_20160425]
Group by date
order by date
```

I also would like to add alias to each table so that i would know from which table the data came from.

please let me know
thanks

Answer (score 1):

The way to union tables in BQ is by using table wildcard functions.
your query should look something like:
(If you share your data-set, we can verify the suggested query)

```
SELECT 
    date as Date,
    SUM(totals.visits) as TotalVisits
    From
    TABLE_QUERY(1243,'table_id contains"ga_sessions_"')
    Group by date
    order by date
```

Comment: the way to Union is by using table wildcard functions such as Table_Query() or Table_Date_Range().

Comment: TABLE_QUERY(1243,'table_id contains"ga_sessions_"')
how do i add multiple tables in this query?
    TABLE_QUERY(1243,45654,'table_id contains"ga_sessions_"')?

Comment: Put the logic that includ all table names between the ''